# The method add(Course, Object[], int) in the type ArrayList<Course> is not applicable for the arguments [Java]

Tags: java

I am having troubles to transfer the data from an array to an ArrayList. I am getting the error: The method add(Course, Object[], int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, int, int, String, int, String). I already checked the data fields in the class Course, they are all correct.

Please help me!

```
ArrayList<Course> coursesList = new ArrayList<Course>();
boolean exit = false;

String fileName = "MyUniversityCoursesFile.csv";
String line = null;

try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] coursesArray = line.split(",");
        String courseName = coursesArray[0];
        String courseID = coursesArray[1];
        String maxStudents = coursesArray[2];
        String registeredStudents = coursesArray[3];
        // String studentsList = coursesArray[4];
        String instructor = coursesArray[5];
        String sectionNumber = coursesArray[6];
        String location = coursesArray[7];  
            
        coursesList.add(courseName, courseID, Integer.parseInt(maxStudents), Integer.parseInt(registeredStudents), instructor, Integer.parseInt(sectionNumber), location);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the ArrayList with Course Object, so when adding into the List, you need to create the Course object and then add it.

```
Course newCourse = new Course(courseName, courseID, Integer.parseInt(maxStudents), Integer.parseInt(registeredStudents), instructor, Integer.parseInt(sectionNumber), location);

coursesList.add(newCourse);
```

Also, it good practise to code to an interface, so instead of doing

```
ArrayList<Course> coursesList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Change it to,

```
 List<Course> coursesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @laura No worries, also it's good practice to code to an interface, I have updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: thanks a lot! i have another problem with my code but i am not being able to post it here. i am trying to serialize the data when the program ends and deserialize it when it starts. it is giving a Stream error and I am not sure why?

Comment: @laura, it's better if you raise a different question for that, and can you accept this answer :)